# Child themes of twentysixteen theme

Tags: wordpress

I am using twenty sixteen child theme. I need to modify the theme contents. What are the files I need to modify and how? Can anyone explain it in detail.
Advance thanks.

when i use child theme like this i get  black screen

This is my site https://i.stack.imgur.com/snSX9.png How to extent the full width of my site..

Comment: Child theme mostly have only these data/files `style.css`,`functions.php`, `screenshot.png`.. So have a check @the documentation that i have given below :)

Comment: Both the left and right corners having black screen.. What to do?

Comment: May be due to the container width. Have a check of it. :)

Comment: Even though its not working...

Comment: How to extent the site width?? I dont know where to give?

Comment: You can extend it using the container with sister. :) `.container{margin: 0,auto; width:100%;`. Like this you ca apply in CSS

Comment: No change  in my site, after i give this style what u suggest..

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or what sister. Can you mention me what is the container width you are using..

Comment: In my style, there is no container width is specified brother..

Comment: Then how you are aligning the with of the Webpage to center sister.

Comment: if so provide me the style what you are using to center the Webpage content ..

Comment: I got the answer brother.. Thank you so much.. i increase the width and height of my image..

Comment: Congrats:) Sister... Happy to help you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122161/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-preethi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read the following documentation about the child themes

Child theme inherits all the functionality and styling of it's parent theme. If you are using child theme and a theme update is applied your changes won't be lost or overwitten

You can quickly create child theme for any theme, just follow the steps given below:

1 Create a folder and name it exactly your theme name; append -child in the name. e.g. creating child theme for twentysixteen theme would be called twentysixteen-child this folder should sit beside parent theme under wp-content/themes/

2- Your child theme should have three files.
style.css
functions.php
screenshot.png

3- In functions.php file you can override parent theme functions.

4 In style.css file you can override parent theme CSS code.

5 If you want to change header design then you have to override header.php file. For this copy header.php file of your parent theme and paste it inside your child theme folder. Now, you can modify the child theme header file as per your requirements.

6 Similarly, you can also override footer.php file in your child theme.

For more info have a look over below thread-
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: You cant control the contents over there in theme. It has only one Admin. :)

Comment: All these 5 files are copied from parent theme and paste into child theme ah brother? Its enough?

Comment: No issues sister :)

Comment: In this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes -> read the following part `Creating a Child Theme from a Modified Existing Theme`

Comment: I already modified a parent theme before creating child theme, i Thought that so only its not working properly.. It accepting the child theme styles but black screen is displayed than white.. what can I do?

Comment: You change the `style.css` of the parent theme and check it once whether it works for you.(i.e) before updating what you had check with that.

Comment: I removed the changes what i made in parent theme still i got a black screen in background..

Comment: This worked for you ah sister after changing the style.css back to normal.

Comment: Ya its working brother.. but black screen only appearing at the background of my site.. what I do for that??

Comment: Share the screenshot so that let me find any solutions for that sister :)

Comment: Lat me know after sharing the screenshot sister:)

Comment: Ok sure brother i Send the screen shot

Comment: Thanks sister. Pleasure helping you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create at-least one child-theme directory and two main files (style.css & functions.php) under child theme directory. I have given example using [Twenty-Thirteen WordPress theme](http://www.codextutor.com/creating-child-theme-in-wordpress/). Step by step explanation is given